# Phalcon Annotations Router throws exception regarding the DI

Tags: php, annotations, router, phalcon

I'm trying to use annotations router but I'm facing the below exception

`A dependency injection container is required to access the 'annotations' service`

You can review my settings and configurations below

Setting up annotations router in public/index.php

```
$di->set('router', function () {
    $router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router\Annotations(false);
    $router->addResource('User');
    return $router;
});
```

My UserController.php

```
/**
 * @RoutePrefix("/user")
 */
class UserController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    /**
     * @Get("/signin")
     */
    public function signinAction()
    {
    }
}
```

When point my browser to `domain/user/signin` I face the mentioned exception. I would appreciate any kind of help as I'm new to the world of Phalcon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following invocation solves problem.

```
$router->setUriSource(\Phalcon\Mvc\Router::URI_SOURCE_SERVER_REQUEST_URI);
```